# MONGO get only the name of documents but not the whole documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

query mongo to find only the names : in such a way that it should be fast, 
ie i don't want to get each document and then get the name from each of them.

I am new to mongo,
db.company.find() --> this will give whole document Which is VERY BIG

NOTE  ; i have used indexing to the company name & also the unique condition too. soo --> i think it should help me finding the company name fast and 
easily , **BUT i don't know how**

**this is the collection**

```
collection company :      --> list of companies in the collection    

 {

    {   
       "_id": "5b8ed214b460e7c17c5a33f9",
        "company_location": "USA",
        "company_name": "tesla",         -----> COMPANY NAME: TESLA
        "cars": 
            [
                 {---car 1---} ,
                 {---car 2---} ,
                 {---car n---} 
            ],
    },

    {   
       "_id": "5b8ed214b460e7c17c5a33f9",
        "company_location": "USA",
        "company_name": "gmc",         -----> COMPANY NAME :GMC
        "cars": 
            [
                 {---car 1---} ,
                 {---car 2---} ,
                 {---car n---} 
            ],
    },

    {   
       "_id": "5b8ed214b460e7c17c5a33f9",
        "company_location": "USA",
        "company_name": "bmw",         -----> COMPANY NAME:BMW
        "cars": 
            [
                 {---car 1---} ,
                 {---car 2---} ,
                 {---car n---} 
            ],
    },
    {   
       "_id": "5b8ed214b460e7c17c5a33f9",
        "company_location": "USA",
        "company_name": "audi",         -----> COMPANY NAME: AUDI
        "cars": 
            [
                 {---car 1---} ,
                 {---car 2---} ,
                 {---car n---} 
            ],
    },
}
```

**So**   I just want the list of company names, and not the whole company collection using `db.companies.find()`. --> and then finding the names of each of them by traversing it

**How can i do this : fast is necessary, data is huge**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use second parameter of `.find()` method to specify a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

```
db.companies.find({}, { _id: 0, company_name: 1 })
```

which returns:

```
{ "company_name" : "gmc" }
{ "company_name" : "tesla" }
...
```

Or you can use Aggregation Framework to get single document with an array of names:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: null, company_names: { $push: "$company_name" } } }])
```

which returns:

```
{ "_id" : null, "company_names" : [ "gmc", "tesla", ... ] }
```

First one should be the fastest way if you have an index on `company_name`. In that case your query don't need to scan collection and can use only index to get queried data ([covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query)).

Comment: which one is fast

Comment: @user6202188 The MongoDB aggregation pipeline is naturally going to be a bit slower on initial execution. The find query could be slower as it grabs data in batches, however. Even so, neither of these commands should be particularly slow at all. Your biggest concern is going to be how much data you're processing, as a large collection of documents could exceed the limits of the aggregation pipeline. Your best bet is probably to just use the `.find()` with projection. If you do find yourself running into performance problems regardless, you might need better indexing.

Comment: Query projection along with proper indexing will allow the query to retrieve results using only the index. This is called a "covered query". See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query.

Comment: **0** - to not show the field;
**1** - show the value