# printing all values for 1 field from each document in 1 collection mongoDB python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

My current document structure looks like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5rdfgd63sdg'),
 'car': '1.16958',
 'bike': '1.16968',
 'van': '1.16951',
 'sedan': '1.16954',
 'volume': 25}
```

I have 500 documents like this in a single collection. I would like to query all values from `'bike'` for example.

The SQL equivalent of what I'd like is `SELECT bike from db.name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a single field in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MONGO get only the name of documents but not the whole documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212165/mongo-get-only-the-name-of-documents-but-not-the-whole-documents/52212258#52212258)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection('collectionName')
  .find({})
  .project({ bike: 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a loop:

```
for x in collection.find({}, {"volume": "true"}):
    print(x)
```